# Selecting part of text from list item for the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code for the textbox:

```
<label>Enter the doctor id</label>
         <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="dr_id" id="user_id" class="user_name" >
```

I want to add the string after '-' to the text box.For eg: for Dr. Prashant Salunke-dr.salunke .I must only have dr.salunke in the text box as it is after '-'. I have written some code given below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

   $('#list li').click(function()
   {
    var arr=$(this).text().split('-');
    $('#user_id').val($(arr[1]).text());

   });

});

</script>

 <a href="#" class="show_hide">List of doctors</a><br />
    <div class="slidingDiv">
<ul id="list">
    <li style="cursor:hand;">Dr.Prashant Salunke - dr.salunke.</li>
    <li style="cursor:hand;">Dr.Kalam - dr.apj</li>
    <li style="cursor:hand;">Dr.Manmohan Singh - dr.economics</li>
</ul>
    </div>


</div>
```

But it is not working. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: just replace this line $('#user_id').val($(arr[1]).text()); with $('#user_id').val(arr[arr.length-1]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arr[1]` value does not need to be converted to a jQuery object. You can use it as it is to set the `val()` of the `input`, although using `$.trim` to remove leading/trailing spaces may help:

```
$('#list li').click(function() {
    var arr = $(this).text().split('-');
    $('#user_id').val($.trim(arr[1]));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#list li').click(function () {
    var arr = $(this).text().split('-');
    $('#user_id').val(arr[1]);

    // arr    returns   ["Dr.Prashant Salunke ", " dr.salunke."] 
    // arr[1] returns   dr.salunke. 
});
```

As, `arr[1]` has already the text value, there is no need to do `$(arr[1]).text()` for getting the text value from it.